# Validation for csv files which is exported from Excel

Tags: validation, symfony, mime-types

I create an constrain in symfony to if the uploaded file was a csv file.

```
$fileContraints = new File(array('maxSize' => '2M', 'mimeTypes' => array('text/csv', 'text/plain')));
```

If i upload a csv file which is exported from excel the validation fails. I check the mimetype which was posted

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[12]
  private 'test' => boolean false
  private 'originalName' => string 'Export-20141027.csv' (length=19)
  private 'mimeType' => string 'application/vnd.ms-excel' (length=24)
  private 'size' => int 120634
  private 'error' => int 0
```

And then i check file mimetype on server

```
 file -b --mime <filename>
```

and get as ouptut

```
text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

The outputed file types from php and console are different. How can i handle this to get an correct mimetype validation of my posted file?

Comment: you should add application/vnd.ms-excel to you accepted mime-types array

Comment: If i add "application/vnd.ms-excel" as valid mime type the user can also upload "xls" files.